# I'm trying to get a random element in an array, why wont my simple code work?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to get this snippet of code to work in a much larger solution, the problem is that the random part of the code never gets -1, only ever 0, 1 or 2 and 2 isn't even in the array. Can't figure this one out but its probably something simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dy(0), dx(0);
    const int setSize = 3;
    int numbers[setSize] = { -1, 0, 1 };

    for (int i(0); i < 50; ++i) {
        dy = 0; dx = 0;
        while (dx == 0 && dy == 0) { // makes sure the zombie actually moves somewhere
            dx = rand() % setSize;
            dy = rand() % setSize;
        } 

        cout << "\n" << dy << "\t" << dx;
    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You're never actually accessing values in the array. Try `numbers[dx]` and `numbers[dy]`.

Comment: Thanks. Should have got that, how could the code ever work ha. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 2):

`rand() % setSize` will give a number up to, but not including, `setSize`, as you noticed. You need to use this as an array index to get a random member of the array.

```
dx = numbers[rand() % setSize];
```

Comment: Christ, I've been at this all day and I guess I need to give my brain a rest. Thank you very much.